# Ragged Nested Numpy Array to Tensor

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have ragged nested arrays of .npy file that I have processed. The error is that it my model failed to convert the NumPy array to a Tensor with the remark 'Unsupported object type list') I have try to use the np.array(seq, type"object") in advance to settle the upper part of the codes as I give out a warning regarding my ragged nested array.

The first block:

```
sequences, labels = [], []
for action in actions:
    for sequence in np.array(os.listdir(os.path.join(DATA_PATH, action))).astype(int):
        window = []
        while True:
            try:
                for frame_num in range(sequence_length):
                    res = np.load(os.path.join(DATA_PATH, action, str(sequence), "{}.npy".format(frame_num)))
                    print(action, sequence, frame_num)
                    window.append(res)
                    
            except FileNotFoundError:
                    break
        sequences.append(window)
        labels.append(label_map[action])
```

The second block is where I adjust my code a bit

```
np.array(sequences, dtype="object").shape
```

The third block is where I have a problem of being unable to convert the NumPy array to Tensor.

```
log_dir = os.path.join('Logs')
tb_callback = TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, activation='relu', input_shape=(30,1662)))
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, activation='relu'))
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=False, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(actions.shape[0], activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=200, callbacks=[tb_callback])
```

The error is as below :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [54], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=200, callbacks=[tb_callback])

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:67, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65 except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68 finally:
     69   del filtered_tb

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py:102, in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    100     dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
    101 ctx.ensure_initialized()
--> 102 return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)

ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a ragged tensor.  You have to correct the 'raggedness' of the array.

Comment: May I know how to do that Sir?

Comment: The elements of `sequences` do not have a consistent size.  If `np.array(sequences, dtype=float)` doesn't work,you can't make a tensor from it.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor#:~:text=Ragged%20tensors%20are%20the%20TensorFlow,as%20sentences%20or%20video%20clips.  Isn't this a ragged tensor?